# Is std::mutex as a member variable thread-safe for multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

Is std::mutex as a member variable thread-safe for multiple threads?

There is an instance of a class has a variable and mutex as a member.

Each function is called in different threads.

I am curious that is it okay to use a mutex like this?

There are lots of example codes using a kind of wrapper class for mutex like guard or something.

I prefer to use it simply and want to unlock explicitly. Not in destructing time.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
private:
  bool _is;
  std::mutex _mutex;
}

// this function runs in Thread A
void A::read() {
  _mutex.lock();
  printf("%d", _is);
  _mutex.unlock();
}

// this function runs in Thread B
void A::write() {
  _mutex.lock();
  printf("%d", _is);
  _is = !_is;
  _mutex.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's OK. A `mutex` that is itself susceptible to a data race would be pretty useless. It's quite interesting that you think manually unlocking the mutex is somehow *simpler* than using a `lock_guard`.

Comment: This only works if both threads access the same instance of `A`. That is not clear from the description

Comment: Sorry, it is same instance.

Comment: @Praetorian The definition of "data race" implies a normal variable, not a synchronisation primitive.

Answer (score 11):

It will basically work, but there are a couple of "gotchas" you'll want to watch out for:

1. If the code in between the `lock()` and `unlock()` calls ever throws an exception (or uses the `return` or `goto` keywords), the `unlock()` call might never be reached, and thus your mutex will remain locked indefinitely.  This will probably result in the deadlocking of your application, as every subsequent thread that tries to the lock the mutex will end up waiting forever for their own `lock()` call to return.  (This hazard goes away if you use a lock_guard/[RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) approach instead, which is why that is the recommended/safer way to do it)
2. If the `A` object gets deleted while it is still accessible to other threads, it will likely result in undefined behavior, since the member-variable-mutex the threads depend on for serialization will have been destroyed.  (The typical way to avoid this is to make sure all threads have been `join()`'d *before* the mutexes they depend on are destructed -- or by moving the mutexes out of the object and into some higher-level object that you can guarantee won't get destroyed while the threads are still running)

Comment: Thanks. It is very helpful.

Comment: #2 can be prevented with a smart pointer like std::shared_ptr.